# Map Chart works in Power Map but does not work in the Power View Map

Tags: excel, powerpivot, powerview

I am building a simple map report using Excel 2013 with Power Map and Power View. I struggle to understand why the same data are displayed correctly in Power Map; however, fails to display anything in Power View (either from the Excel range or Power Pivot).

Please can anyone give me heads up what I am missing?

Sample Data:

```
+----------+-------------+--------------+---------+--------------+
| Customer |  Latitude   |  Longitude   | Country | Constituency |
+----------+-------------+--------------+---------+--------------+
|     6394 | 53.97046592 | -1.080241735 | England | York Outer   |
|     5643 | 53.95796996 | -1.091323488 | England | York Central |
+----------+-------------+--------------+---------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to make a Power View map with your data. I put a count of the Customer field as my size, Constituency as my location, and then used the longitude and latitude fields. It worked for me using the Range or adding the data to a Power Pivot model. [image]

A couple of tips:

- Put Constituency in the locations field so you can see the 2 points.
- In Power Pivot, on the Advanced tab, set the data category to Latitude or Longitude for the appropriate field and it will always recognize it as geography.